# Enabling ZLib support in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I'm installing a PHP script in my server and when I try to run the test page, I get an error saying:

```
PHP needs to be compiled with ZLib support enabled (--with-zlib[=DIR])
```

How can I fix this on Apache?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is on linux?

As the error says, you need to recompile your PHP installation.

Take a look at the Makefile in the folder where you have the PHP source to see the ./configure line that was used last time, use all of the same options with the addition of --with-zlib

```
./configure --with-zlib ...(other config options)...
make
make install
```